# Debugging a Python/Django app using Visual Studio Code VCS problem with the Terminate or stop button after a breakpoint but execution continues

Tags: visual-studio-code, debugging, breakpoints, termination

I have been working on a Python/django app for quite sometime. Normally when I set a breakpoint the program would stop execution and I could step into the code and perform my debugging. However, sometime during the last few weeks my VSC was updated to version 1.79.2 and since then I have the following problem.

When the breakpoint gets tripped and the code stops executing, when I hit the RED terminate or stop button the program does not stop executing, instead it continues running code and ignores any remaining breakpoints. If I hit the red button twice the VSC terminate execution (debugging) but code is executed beyond the initial breakpoint.

This has never happened to me before. When I used to hit the red button, the execution simply terminated and debugging stopped. Has anyone else had this problem? Any ideas on how to fix this problem? Is it a setting perhaps?

I tried adding a quit() or exit() to my python code much farther down the program to stop the code from executing while I try and resolve this problem. Sure enough when the breakpoint tripped and execution stopped, I hit the STOP red button on the ribbon and code resumed execution until it was stopped by the quit() command. I tried stepping though the breakpoint and all that worked normally. It is just the stop that is a problem.

Comment: please add the version info of the Python extension you are using. Show a [mre] as well, with a comment pointing to where to put the breakpoint.